# Как получить картинку текущего курсора мыши?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

Захват экрана выполняется стандартными функциями GDI - `CreateDIBSection`, `SelectObject`, `BitBlt` и т.д. Но курсора на таком скриншоте нет, а он нужен. Хочу получить координаты курсора и вручную нарисовать его на полученном скриншоте.

**Как получить его графическое представление?** *`HBITMAP`, RGB буфер - что угодно, лишь бы это можно было нарисовать в DC.*

**Спасибо за комментарии и ответ - разобрался!**

После `BitBlt` самого экрана нужно:

```
CURSORINFO CursorInfo;
CursorInfo.cbSize = sizeof(CursorInfo);
if (GetCursorInfo(&CursorInfo)){
    ICONINFO IconInfo;
    GetIconInfo(CursorInfo.hCursor, &IconInfo);
    DeleteObject(IconInfo.hbmColor);
    DeleteObject(IconInfo.hbmMask);
    DrawIcon(MemoryDC, CursorInfo.ptScreenPos.x - IconInfo.xHotspot, CursorInfo.ptScreenPos.y - IconInfo.yHotspot, CursorInfo.hCursor);
}
```

Comment: [`CopyImage()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms648031(v=vs.85).aspx) ?

Comment: вообще по с++ не знаю но на Delphi: `DrawIcon(image1.Canvas.handle, 10,10, getCursor());` рисует курсор.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469538/winapi-get-mouse-cursor-icon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Информацию о курсоре получить с помощью `GetCursorInfo()`

Тут довольно подробно расписано как получить:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12850/Capturing-the-Desktop-Screen-with-the-Mouse-Cursor

Там же есть исходник с примером. C# и C++ разницы в win32 API не будет, синтаксис только немного другой.